# How to fetch user's email using Facebook?

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook

I am new to iOS. I am able to fetch `first_name`,`last_name` of user(Facebook) using `loginViewFetchedUserInfo` method of `FBLoginView` but I want to know how to fetch the email,birthday and etc.

Here is my code:

in `viewDidLoad`

```
FBLoginView *loginview = [[FBLoginView alloc] init];
loginview.readPermissions=@[@"email"];
loginview.frame = CGRectOffset(loginview.frame, 5, 5);
loginview.delegate = self;

[self.view addSubview:loginview];

[loginview sizeToFit];
```

After this how and where can I fetch the email address of the user?

I have gone through so many posts but they didn't make any sense to me, so please help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

for new code  facebook SDK ver 4.0 and above

see this [link](http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-how-to-use-login-in-facebook-sdk-4-0-for-swift/)

below

```
 //  use facebook SDK 3.8
```

add the following methods in AppDelegate.m

```
 -(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:  (NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
return [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication  fallbackHandler:^(FBAppCall *call)
        {
            NSLog(@"Facebook handler");
        }
        ];
}


- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
[FBAppEvents activateApp];
[FBAppCall handleDidBecomeActive];
// Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
 [FBSession.activeSession close];
// Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}
```

se the follwing code in your viewcontroler .h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<FBLoginViewDelegate>


@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblUserName;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtEmailId;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *lblCreate;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet FBProfilePictureView *profilePic;

@property (strong, nonatomic) id<FBGraphUser> loggedInUser;

- (IBAction)butCreate:(id)sender;

- (void)showAlert:(NSString *)message
       result:(id)result
        error:(NSError *)error;

@end
```

// apply the below code to your view controller.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
FBLoginView *loginview=[[FBLoginView alloc]initWithReadPermissions:@[@"email",@"user_likes"]];
loginview.frame=CGRectMake(60, 50, 200, 50);
loginview.delegate=self;
[loginview sizeToFit];
[self.view addSubview:loginview];

}

-(void)loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView
{
self.lblCreate.enabled=YES;
self.txtEmailId.enabled=YES;
self.lblUserName.enabled=YES;


}

-(void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user
{
self.lblUserName.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",user.name];
self.txtEmailId.text=[user objectForKey:@"email"];
//self.profilePic.profileID=user.id;
self.loggedInUser=user;
}

-(void)loginViewShowingLoggedOutUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView
{

self.txtEmailId.text=nil;
self.lblUserName.text=nil;
self.loggedInUser=nil;
self.lblCreate.enabled=NO;

}
-(void)loginView:(FBLoginView *)loginView handleError:(NSError *)error{
   NSLog(@"Show the Error ==%@",error);
}
```

**Swift 1.2 & above**

Create a dictionary :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var dict : NSDictionary!
}
```

Fetching the data :

```
if((FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()) != nil){
    FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email"]).startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
        if (error == nil){
            self.dict = result as NSDictionary               
            println(self.dict)
            NSLog(self.dict.objectForKey("picture")?.objectForKey("data")?.objectForKey("url") as String)
        }
    })
}
```

Output should be :

```
{
    email = "karthik.saral@gmail.com";
    "first_name" = Karthi;
    id = 924483474253864;
    "last_name" = keyan;
    name = "karthi keyan";
    picture =     {
        data =         {
            "is_silhouette" = 0;
            url = "XXXXXXX";
        };
    };
}
```

Comment: email is returning null for me please help.

Comment: @PradumnaPatil -- this is old code , which SDK are you used and can you show your code

Comment: I am using facebook sdk version 2.0

Comment: @PradumnaPatil - in here this scenaio also have apply , may be if your email is protected or not available it does not show your email , the above condition is not statisy then we move on this step --> check granted permission for fetch email

Answer (score 2):

try this..

```
if(FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {

       [FBRequestConnection startForMeWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                           id<FBGraphUser> user,
                                                           NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
                       NSString *email = [user objectForKey:@"email"];
                    }
   }];
}
```