# iOS - FBSession & FBRequestMe get user data issue

Tags: ios, facebook

I'm using Facebook iOS SDK v3.13.1 to let users login to their Facebook account. I'm getting user's Facebook ID for my app to use.

First, I use this:

```
FBSession *session = [[FBSession alloc] init];
// Set the active session
[FBSession setActiveSession:session];
// Open the session
[session openWithBehavior:FBSessionLoginBehaviorWithFallbackToWebView completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
    }
}];
```

...to login, and if there is no error, I Call `[[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:]` to get users data.

But it seems it's not working perfectly, some users can log-in successfully, but some users can't.

Most of error were (logged by Flurry):

```
FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed
com.facebook.sdk:UserLoginCancelled
```

Then, I found that document of `[FBSession openWithBehavior]` wrote:

> A session may not be used with  and other classes in the
>   SDK until it is open. If, prior to calling open, the session is in the
>   FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded> state, then no UX occurs, and the
>   session becomes available for use.

Does it mean that I can't use this method with `FBRequest` together, or it'll cause error?

Should I use `FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions` instead?

Comment: use this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19563158/how-to-fetch-users-email-using-fbloginview/19563502#19563502

Comment: any queries, I am waiting

Comment: Yeah, I've checked that post before, but my question is: Is it wrong to use [FBSession openWithBehavior] and [FBRequest requestForMe] together?

Comment: [FBRequest requestForMe] it is fine

Comment: Stil no good answer...but I'm using openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions now...thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

```
accessTokan = [[[FBSession activeSession] accessTokenData] accessToken];
                 //NSLog(@"%@",accessTokan);


             NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
             [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=%@",accessTokan]]];
             [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
             [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
             NSError *error;
             NSURLResponse *response;
             NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
             NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

             NSLog(@"%@",str);
             fb_dict = [str JSONValue];
             [str release];

             NSLog(@"%@",fb_dict);
```