# IOS switch view after FB login

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, uinavigationcontroller, xcode5

I use the storyboard, and the first view is FB login. I want to switch view to the Navigation controller after FB login successfully (FB login can work).

I don't know how to switch the view. I even use a button and push, but it is not working.

The FBloginViewController class:

```
#import "FBloginViewController.h"
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>

@interface LoginStatusViewController ()

-(void)toggleHiddenState:(BOOL)shouldHide;

@end

@implementation FBLoginViewController

-(void)toggleHiddenState:(BOOL)shouldHide{
    self.lblUsername.hidden = shouldHide;
    self.lblEmail.hidden = shouldHide;
    self.profilePicture.hidden = shouldHide;
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)loginView:(FBLoginView *)loginView handleError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
}

-(void)loginViewShowingLoggedOutUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView{
    self.lblLoginStatus.text = @"You are logged out";

    [self toggleHiddenState:YES];
}

-(void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user{
    NSLog(@"%@", user);
    self.profilePicture.profileID = user.objectID;
    self.lblUsername.text = user.name;
    self.lblEmail.text = [user objectForKey:@"email"];
}

-(void)loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView{
    self.lblLoginStatus.text = @"You are logged in.";
    [self toggleHiddenState:NO];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    [self toggleHiddenState:YES];
    self.lblLoginStatus.text = @"";
    self.loginButton.readPermissions = @[@"public_profile", @"email"];
    self.loginButton.delegate = self;

}
```

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19563158/how-to-fetch-users-email-using-fbloginview/19563502#19563502

Comment: if u need any help I hope with u

Comment: The FB login can work, but I don't know how to switch view to the Navigation controller.

Comment: r u using xib or storyboard bro

Comment: if u are using xib use this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20742745/navigation-controller-push-view-controller/20742996#20742996 other wise if u r using storyboard use this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20715462/receiver-viewcontroller-has-no-segue-with-identifier-addsegue/20715545#20715545

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this method in your code at the point wherever you want to perform a switch forward to a new Controller.

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"yourSegueIdentifierName" sender:nil];
```

You will have to connect a segue in the Interface Builder or provide a segue programatically in your application.This method will automatically trigger the `prepareForSegue` method as soon as the above statement is encountered and the next controller will appear.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have to look into how to set up properly the view controllers in the application.

From th question the structure is

> App Launch -> FBLogin -> NAv Contoller -> Next Viewcontroller

Change this to

> App Launch ->NAv Contoller-> FBLogin ->(PUSH)-> Next Viewcontroller

Means embed the navigation controller in the FBLogin VC and continue the workflow

use method `-pushViewController:animated:` to move to next page

Comment: Can you give me a sample code or method? 
Because I don't know how to auto push after FB login successfully...
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Replace your methods with this:

```
-(void)loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView{
   self.lblLoginStatus.text = @"You are logged in.";
   [self toggleHiddenState:NO];
   //if you have anavigation controller then
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"yourSegueIdentifierName" sender:nil];
   //if you want to open a modal viewController
   YOURVIEWCONTROLLER *vc1 = [[YOURVIEWCONTROLLER alloc] initWithNibName:@"YOURVIEWCONTROLLER" bundle:nil];
   [vc1 setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
   [self presentViewController:vc1 animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```