# Facebook SDK loginViewShowingLoggedInUser not getting called

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I'm new to iOS and trying to implement Facebook login and after login is successful I want it to go to another view. I've done everything that the documentation shows but I can't get the delegate to be called. I have seen people questions but I tried all of them. Nothing worked not sure if I miss something obvious.

This is my LoginViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>

@interface LoginViewController : UIViewController <FBLoginViewDelegate>

@end
```

This is my LoginViewController.m file

```
#import "LoginViewController.h"

@interface LoginViewController ()

@end

@implementation LoginViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
        NSLog(@"Starting");
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    FBLoginView *loginView = [[FBLoginView alloc] init];
    loginView.delegate = self;

    return YES;
}

-(void)loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView {
    NSLog(@"You're logged in");
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueToAnotherView" sender:self];

}

-(void)loginViewShowingLoggedOutUser:(FBLoginView *)logoutView {
    NSLog(@"Logged out");
}



@end
```

I also have this in my AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {

    // Call FBAppCall's handleOpenURL:sourceApplication to handle Facebook app responses
    BOOL wasHandled = [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication];

    // You can add your app-specific url handling code here if needed

    return wasHandled;
}
```

When the app comes back I don't see the log "You're logged in" or even "Logged out" at all. I can only see the Logout button from Facebook. Also, the two view controllers are connected by a segue.

Comment: try this link may be useful for u ...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19563158/how-to-fetch-users-email-using-fbloginview/19563502#19563502

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to want to add your app to Facebook, Download the Facebook SDK and add some values to your plist. There is a lot more you're going to need to do here and I suggest you read [Facebook SDK Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/?platform=ios) If you need more help, I am brand new to iOS as well and just implemented my own Facebook login (I guess you could call it custom) and it works smoothly.

Comment: Actually you were right, I missed something really obvious.  which is that line [FBLoginView class];

Comment: There you go! I had so many problems with the whole Facebook SDK and then someone else I believe directed me to that link. I read a little, and I was missing so many little things. Regardless, I'm glad the documentation helped you! @toy

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the following code to log in from facebook

```
#define PERMISSION @"publish_actions",@"email",@"public_profile" 

@property (strong, nonatomic) FBSession *session;


NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:PERMISSION,nil];


    self.session = [[FBSession alloc] initWithPermissions:permissions];



    [FBSession setActiveSession:self.session];


    // if the session isn't open, let's open it now and present the login UX to the user
    [self.session openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                              FBSessionState status,
                                                              NSError *error) {

        if (!error) {

          //Handle code for success


        } else {

           //Code for failure
        }

    }];
```