# FBLoginView keeps redirecting back to app

Tags: ios, facebook

I am trying to use FBLoginView to create a login/logout button in my test app, but the login page keeps redirecting back to my app.  It worked for the first, say 2 times, but then stopped working.  The log is not spitting out any error.  My code is as follows:

In .h file:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet FBLoginView *loginView;
```

In .m file:

```
_loginView.readPermissions = @[@"name", @"email", @"phone"];
```

Am I supposed to include the following statements?

```
FBLoginView *loginView = [[FBLoginView alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview:loginView];
```

Those statements duplicated the button that I created in IB, so I deleted them.  How should I remove this bug?  Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

*P.S. Please do not vote down on this post.  If there is anything wrong, please express why in the comments section.  Thank you.*

Comment: what you tried, `FBLoginView` is a `UIView` its automatically created the view, k in which type login u need , like custom button login or this FBLoginView

Comment: if you use a custom button use this[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25602504/login-with-facebook-using-custom-button/25603344#25603344) if you use loginview use this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19563158/how-to-fetch-users-email-using-fbloginview/19563502#19563502)

Comment: I already created the view in IB, so...  does that cover it?

Comment: if you use the button from your IB , then you tried the custom login I suggest the two links for you , refere

Comment: Hmm.. I am following this (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.2) tutorial and they don't tell me to create any special method.

Comment: there are two ways to use the Facebook login my friend, if you use custom method the apple does not reject your app

Comment: Could you walk me through the idea of that code?  I am not trying to access any field, so I am just wondering which pieces to take and not.

Comment: sure my friend I surely help you

Comment: Would it be too much trouble to post the code with annotations in the answers section?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing on a device? If yes, if on tapping the login button you are redirected back to your app it means that you have already granted permission to the app. This is correct behaviour.

If you want to remove/edit these permissions, go to your [settings](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications) and remove the permissions for your app. If you remove your app from settings altogether, then you'll see the login view again which will ask for permissions when you tap on the login button of your app.

You do not need:

```
FBLoginView *loginView = [[FBLoginView alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview:loginView];
```

As you have already created the FBLogin view in the IB. This block of code does the same thing but programmatically. So do either, not both.

```
_loginView.readPermissions = @[@"name", @"email", @"phone"];
```

- 'name' and 'phone' are not valid permission types.

Depending on your requirements, you can use other permissions e.g.

```
_loginView.readPermissions = @[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends"];
```

If you only want to use login then 'public_profile' should suffice.